# Dynamic div width inside another div

Tags: dynamic, html, width

I have 2 inline divs inside a parent div:

```
.parent {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
.div1 {
    float: left;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.div2 {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    right: 0px;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}
```

The problem is that `div2` inherits the width of the `parent` div instead of the remaining width (i.e. 190px) and ultimately div2 ends up below div1.

Here is an example using jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jZBE6/

How can I make div2 have a width of 190px without setting a static width?

Comment: please mark an answer and get this off the active question list :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
.parent{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}

.div1 {
   float: left;
   width:10px;
   height:10px;
   background-color:blue;
}

.div2{
    height:100%;
    width:90%;
    float:left;
    background-color:red;
}
```

You could also do it without floating the right div (this is the way I would prefer):

```
.parent{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}

.div1 {
    float: left;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background-color:blue;
}

.div2{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin-left:10px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in case you really want a dynamic width (not just 10px case), you can't use css. But you can use javascript to set width dynamically http://jsfiddle.net/jZBE6/19/